# AWS Step function calling Batch Job

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

We are trying to build a service which would use event bridge to call a step function and the step function would call the batch job to execute the defined set of tasks.
The batch job is actually using an EC2 Container to run a Java code and it should return the output. We had an implementation for the same but we got a new set of instructions where in there are 6 set of functions written in Java and the batch job should decide on how to call it as per the schedule in event bridge.

So the flow is event bridge -> 1 step function -> 1 batch job -> ec2 container ->runs Java code.
What we want to do if possible is to reuse the same step function and batch job and pass on arguments which can decide on which Java code to run during the call

What we did was in the entry.sh file in docker, we decided to pass the arguments from the batch so that docker will determine which java code to call.

We are unsure if this approach would work as we need bit more clarity on how can we pass the arguments to the docker from the step function. Could someone provide some insights?